# Why I can't set multi rows in recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I wanna set multi rows in adapter but this is not working I don't know why

*Chat Adapter*

```
public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        Context context;
        List<ChatModel> chatModels;

        public ChatAdapter(Context context, List<ChatModel> chatModels) {
            this.context = context;
            this.chatModels = chatModels;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            ChatModel chatModel = chatModels.get(i);
            if (chatModel.me.equals("yes")) {
                return new Black_Message(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_black, viewGroup, false));
            } else if (chatModel.me.equals("no")) {
                return new Yellow_Message(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_yellow, viewGroup, false));
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
            ChatModel chatModel = chatModels.get(i);
            if (chatModel.me.equals("yes")) {
                Black_Message black_message = (Black_Message) viewHolder;
                black_message.text_title.setText(chatModel.question);
            } else if (chatModel.me.equals("no")) {
                Yellow_Message yellow_message = (Yellow_Message) viewHolder;
                yellow_message.text_title.setText(chatModel.answers);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return chatModels.size();
        }

        class Black_Message extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            @BindView(R.id.relative_layout)
            RelativeLayout relative_layout;
            @BindView(R.id.text_title)
            TextViewFont text_title;

            public Black_Message(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            }
        }

        class Yellow_Message extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            @BindView(R.id.relative_layout)
            RelativeLayout relative_layout;
            @BindView(R.id.text_title)
            TextViewFont text_title;

            public Yellow_Message(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            }
        }

    }
```

I hope you tell me where is error.........................................................................................................................................

Comment: Have you checked chatModels which you pass to constructor? Can you check its size in the constructor to be sure you are passing the right thing?

Comment: @MeHdi there is no any problem

Comment: Have you checked the RecyclerView layout width and height? Does it actually draw on the screen or not? You can check it by turning on "show layout bounds" from developer options (if you don't know where it is just google it)

Comment: What is the issue exactly? Show what you see on the logs. Is there an exception? Or some other bug?

Comment: I found solution thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution

```
public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<ChatModel> chatModels;

    public ChatAdapter(Context context, List<ChatModel> chatModels) {
        this.context = context;
        this.chatModels = chatModels;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        if (i == 1) {
            return new Black_Message(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_black, viewGroup, false));
        } else if (i == 2) {
            return new Yellow_Message(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_yellow, viewGroup, false));
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        ChatModel chatModel = chatModels.get(i);
        if (chatModel.me.equals("yes")) {
            Black_Message black_message = (Black_Message) viewHolder;
            black_message.text_title.setText(chatModel.question);
        } else if (chatModel.me.equals("no")) {
            Yellow_Message yellow_message = (Yellow_Message) viewHolder;
            yellow_message.text_title.setText(chatModel.answers);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return chatModels.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        ChatModel chatModel = chatModels.get(position);
        if (chatModel.me.equals("yes")) {
            return 1;
        } else if (chatModel.me.equals("no")) {
            return 2;
        }else {
            return super.getItemViewType(position);
        }
    }

    class Black_Message extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.relative_layout)
        RelativeLayout relative_layout;
        @BindView(R.id.text_title)
        TextViewFont text_title;

        public Black_Message(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }

    class Yellow_Message extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.relative_layout)
        RelativeLayout relative_layout;
        @BindView(R.id.text_title)
        TextViewFont text_title;

        public Yellow_Message(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }

}
```